# Android repetitive http connection

Tags: android, httpclient, httpconnection

I have scenario where i need to make http calls to same url couple of times in one second. Currently i`am making new HttpConnection, HttpClient... etc from beginning over and over again for every new request. This solution works fine, but it seems very inefficient to me. Is there way to make repetitive http requests to same url in more efficient way? Example to reuse some of already allocated variables?

Comment: You can have all your code for API hit in a AsyncTask or IntentService and just start the Service or execute the Async..

Comment: Yes i can, but that is not an issue here. Actually a have different thread doing all the http requests in background. I need some more memory and processing time efficient method.

Comment: Also keep in mind that you might be using a lot of battery in the process read this-> http://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/efficient-network-access.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use a static http client (so that gurentees it's created just once) and then reuse it with all requests without having to create new instances of it, you can use this logic for many other fixed variables related to the connection in order to save memory.